# expectations of Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expectation

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion started at zero, and let $M_t$ be a
stochastic process defined by
$M_t=3\int_0^{t^{1/9}} s^4dB_s$

Compute $E\left[1+\int_0^t(1+M_s)^4 dM_s\right]$.

Compute $E\left[{M_t}^2\int_0^t M_s dM_s\right]$.

I have already shown that $M_t$ is a standard Brownian motion by showing $\langle M,M\rangle =t$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, we know that $(s,\omega) \mapsto (1+M_s(\omega))^4$ is integrable with respect to $L^2(\lambda_T \otimes \mathbb{P})$ for any $T>0$. Consequently,  the stochastic integral $$X_t := \int_0^t (1+M_s)^4 \, dM_s$$ is a martingale; in particular it has constant expectation.
2. Using Itô's formula, it is not difficult to show that $$\int_0^t M_s \, dM_s = \frac{M_t^2-t}{2}.$$ Therefore, $$\mathbb{E} \left(M_t^2 \cdot \int_0^t M_s \, dM_s \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathbb{E}(M_t^4) - t \cdot \mathbb{E}(M_t^2) \right).$$ As $M_t \sim N(0,t)$ for each $t \geq 0$, the expectations on the right hand side are known.

Comment: hi thanks for answering, I understand that $(1+M_s)^4$ is integrable but how does this prove that the integral is a martingale and how would you find out the value of the constant expectation?  By any chance would it be equal to 0 as it is an ito integral?

Comment: @user120678 It is a martingale since it is a stochastic integral with respect to a Brownian motion (i.e. an Itô integral, as you call it). In particular, $\mathbb{E}X_t = \mathbb{E}X_0=0$.

Comment: great thanks a lot, is $E[X_t]=E[X_0]$ due to the fact it is a martingale and $X_0=0$? For the second question would you apply itos formula to $M_t^2$? also

Comment: @user120678 Any martingale has constant expectation value since $\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$ implies $$\mathbb{E}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s)) = \mathbb{E}(X_s).$$ And yes, for the second question I would apply Itô's formula to $M_t^2$.

Comment: great thanks for your help!

Comment: @user120678 If the answer satisfies you, you can can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.